Why do we need this inequality?
I have been going through a state maths exam and am not able to answer the following question. I understand that $k>-1/4$. However, in the solutions it is also stated that $e^{-x}>0$. Why does this need to happen?
Question Context
Question:

Find the values of $k$ such that the curves $y =e^{-2x}$ and $y=e^{-x}+k$ intersect at two points.

Solutions provided by exam board
Thanks.

Hint : if $~a > 0, ~$ then $~\dfrac{1}{a} > 0.~$  Is $~e^x~$ ever $~\leq 0,~$ for any $~x \in \Bbb{R}~?$  What does the graph of $~y = e^x~$ look like ?

Intuitively, note that $e^{-x}+k$ has an asymptote $y=k$. But of course this doesn't prove anything.

@BenjaminWang Perhaps I am misinterpreting the question.  The way that I interpret the question, the original poster is simply asking why it is, that for all $~x \in \Bbb{R},~$ the expression $~e^{-x}~$ is always positive.

@user2661923 Yes! Why is it that the solutions solve the inequality for $e^{-x}<0$? Why can't I leave the solution at $k>-1/4$?

For what it's worth, virtually every MathSE posted question that I have seen, that followed this article on MathSE protocol has been upvoted rather than downvoted.  I am not necessarily advocating this protocol.  Instead, I am merely stating a fact: if you scrupulously follow the linked article, skipping/omitting nothing, you virtually guarantee a positive response.

Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Suppose $k > 0$ and suppose $e^{-2x}= e^{-x} + k$  Then $[e^{-x}]^2 - e^{-x} - k = 0$ so $e^{-x} = \frac {1\pm \sqrt{1+4k}}2$ so we have either $e^{-x} = \frac{1+\sqrt{1+4k}}2$ and $x = -\ln [ \frac{1+\sqrt{1+4k}}2]$  or we have $e^{-x} = \frac {1-\sqrt{1+4k}}2 < 0$.  That is impossible so that can not be a solutions.  So there is only ONE point of interesection:  $x = -\ln [ \frac{1+\sqrt{1+4k}}2]$ .  We were asked for $2$ points of intersection and that is impossible if $k > 0$.

We need two things.  We need $1+4k \ge 0$ and we need BOTH $\frac {1+\sqrt{1+4k}}2>0$ and $\frac {1-\sqrt{1+4k}}2 >0$.  The first happens if and only if $k \ge -\frac 14$ and the second DOESN'T happen if $k \ge 0$.  So we must have both $k \ge -\frac 14$ and $k < 0$.

" Yes! Why is it that the solutions solve the inequality for e−x<0? Why can't I leave the solution at k>−1/4?"  Okay.  Let $k = 6$.  How many solutions does $e^{-2x} = e^{-x} + 6$ have?  What are they?  Try and solve it and see what happens.

So you were right to say $k>−1/4$, you say your confused with how $e^{-x} >0$,
This is simply due to the fact that $e^x$ for any real value of $x$, is positive.
Since the equations are based on $e^{-x}$, which is $1/e^x$, this would mean $1/positive$ $number$ =  positive number.
Hence x is such a value below infinity, such that $e^{-x}>0$.
The reason I say below infinity is that as x -> infinity,
$1/e^x$ -> 0.
Hence the value of x is such that x is a value below infinity!
Because you cannot have a real number value such that 1/$e^x$ =0.
